# MapView Doesn't Display Map on Samsung S Duos

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, google-maps-api-2

I am using Google map API v2 in my android app. The map is working probably on all devices _ that I tested the app on it _ but Samsung S Duos with android version 4.1.2 though it works on Galaxy S3 mini with android version 4.1.2

When I run the app on Samsung s duos nothing looks wrong in the log Cat.. no errors no warnings.. it runs exactly as it runs on other devices but doesn't show the map.. only showing the zoom buttons and Google word at the bottom of the screen..

Comment: Can you check if `GooglePlayServices` is installed/updated in your device, moreover, without code it's hard to help. I doubt that you are not checking for `GooglePlayServices` in your code.

Comment: Does the Google Maps app work on that device?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response :) I figured out the problem.. it was a strange problem really! the date of the device was incorrect and that lead to an error in network connection.. the WiFi was connected but there was no really connection.. I fixed the date and the map was loaded :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem.. it was a strange problem really! the date of the device was incorrect and that lead to an error in network connection.. the WiFi was connected but there was no really connection.. I fixed the date and the map was loaded :)

I wrote this to help anyone having the same problem! :)